# jquery xml find node with value

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

Hi friends I have below code in XML file. I need to find the value of `<x> <metadata> <field><name>work</name><value>` based on `y` tag value.

## XML File

```
<x>
<y>12</y>
<metadata>
<field>
<name>1234</name>
<value>qqqqqq</value>
</field>
<field>
<name>work</name>
<value>true</value>
</field>
</metadata>
</X>
<x>
<y>14</y>
<metadata>
<field>
<name>5678</name>
<value>wwwww</value>
</field>
<field>
<name>work</name>
<value>false</value>
</field>
</metadata>
</X>
```

## My code

```
y=14;
$.ajax({
        type: "GET" ,
        url: "../JRF/JRF.xml" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
        success: function(xml) {

            $(xml).find('x').each(function(){
                if(y == $(this).find('y').text())
                {
                    ?????????
                }

            }); 
            }       
        });
```

Can u help me to get the value of `<value>` `true` or `false` and I have to store the value in a hidden input text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something you can use:

```
$(xml).find('x').each(function() {
 if (y == $(this).find('y').text()) {
  var trueOrFalse = $(this).find('metadata field:has(name:contains("work")) value').text();
  console.log('work for ' + y + ' is ' + trueOrFalse);
 }
});
```

Basically, it:

- `$(xml).find('x').each(function() {`

  - gets every `x` element in the XML
- `if (y == $(this).find('y').text()) {`

  - if that `x` has an `y` child element whose text contents is equal to `y`
- `$(this).find('metadata field:has(name:contains("work")) value').text();`

  - Breakdown:

    - `$(this).find('metadata field')`

      - it finds the `field` element that is child of a `metadata` element
    - `$(this).find('metadata field:has(name:contains("work"))')`

      - it limits only to those `field` that *have* a `name` child with `"work"` in its contents
    - `$(this).find('metadata field:has(name:contains("work")) value').text();`

      - and this selects the `value` element of the `field:has(name:contains("work"))`, and gets its text.

Demo below.

```js
var xml = `<root>
  <x>
    <y>12</y>
    <metadata>
      <field>
        <name>1234</name>
        <value>qqqqqq</value>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>work</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </field>
    </metadata>
  </x>
  <x>
    <y>14</y>
    <metadata>
      <field>
        <name>5678</name>
        <value>wwwww</value>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>work</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </field>
    </metadata>
  </x>
</root>
`;

var y = 14;
$(xml).find('x').each(function() {
  if (y == $(this).find('y').text()) {
    var trueOrFalse = $(this).find('metadata field:has(name:contains("work")) value').text();
    console.log('work for ' + y + ' is ' + trueOrFalse);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And, if you are into one-liners:

```
$(xml).find('x:has(y:contains("'+ y +'")) metadata field:has(name:contains("work")) value').text();
```

Demo:

```js
var xml = `<root>
  <x>
    <y>12</y>
    <metadata>
      <field>
        <name>1234</name>
        <value>qqqqqq</value>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>work</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </field>
    </metadata>
  </x>
  <x>
    <y>14</y>
    <metadata>
      <field>
        <name>5678</name>
        <value>wwwww</value>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>work</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </field>
    </metadata>
  </x>
</root>
`;

var y = 14;
var trueOrFalse = $(xml).find('x:has(y:contains("'+ y +'")) metadata field:has(name:contains("work")) value').text();
console.log('work for ' + y + ' is ' + trueOrFalse);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: DId you try it out?

Comment: it is very useful for me thanks a lot. U explained me very detailed thank u so much. I need to break the loop once the value is found. can u help me